# linq query to filter with list<int> condition

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I have a list of int which is sent from the data table and I need to filter the overall list with this object.

```
var Ids = new List<int>();  
Ids = {2, 4, 5};

var result = (from m in member
                     join r in role on m.memberId equals r.memberId
                     where
                         Ids.Equals(m.memberId) && r.status = 1
                     select m).ToList();
```

I struck in getting result in single query.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue

```
var Ids = new List<int>();  
Ids = {2, 4, 5};

var result = (from m in member
                     join r in role on m.memberId equals r.memberId
                     where
                         Ids.Any(i=> i == m.memberId) && r.status = 1
                     select m).ToList();
```

Comment: Better option would be to create `HashSet<int>`, use `hashIds.Contains(m.memberId)`, this is better than `List.Any`. Hashset is a O(1) search, when List is O(N)

Comment: @MrinalKamboj That doesn't apply to entity-framework.

Comment: You should be able to just use `Ids.Contains(m.memberId)` instead of `Any` in this case.

Comment: @NetMage missed out the EF tag, considered this to be a Linq 2 Objects query